# Add php variable to ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form on **page 1** and I want to parse its variables to ajax call on **page 2**. The ajax call is triggered by on onload event.

Scenario:

**Page1**

```
<form id="form1"method="GET" action="page2">//send the variables to page 2
<input type="text" name="Place" value="city">
<input type="text" name="Type" value="room">
<input type="submit"></form>
```

**page 2**

```
<form name="myform2" id="myform2" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="Place" value="<?php echo $_GET[Place] ?>">//
<input type="text" name="type" value="<?php echo $_GET[Type] ?>">
<button id="submit2"type="submit" value="submit2" name="submit2" onclick="return ss()">
```

js1

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // load file.php on document ready     
     function sssssss2(page){
          var form2 = document.myform2;
          var dataString1 = $(form2).serialize() + '&page=' + page;
         ({
         type: "GET",
         url: "file.php",//
         data: dataString1,
         success: function(ccc){
             $("#search_results").html(ccc);
        }});}
    sssssss2(1) ;
    $('#search_results .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('p');
        sssssss2(page);                 
    });  
});
```

js2

```
function sss() {//serialize the form each time submitted.
     var form2 = document.myform2;
     var dataString1 = $(form2).serialize();
     $.ajax({
         type:'GET',
         url: "file.php",
         cache: false,
         data: dataString1,
         success: function(data){
             $('#search_results').html(data);
         }
    });
    return false; 
}
```

The problem is the **file.php doens't take the variable "city" and "room"**.I would like to parse the 2 variable to file.php when page2 load first time.

Hw to parse those variable on document load page2?

Comment: It's missing `$.ajax` in js1. And should be `$_GET['Place']`, `$_GET['Type']`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't Place and Type be in quotes like

```
<input type="text" name="Place" value="<?php echo $_GET['Place'] ?>">//
<input type="text" name="type" value="<?php echo $_GET['Type'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you miss a blankspace before 'method' and before 'type' attribute:

```
<form id="form1"method="GET" action="page2">
<button id="submit2"type="submit" value="submit2" name="submit2" onclick="return ss()">
```

Here you miss an action attribute:

```
<form name="myform2" id="myform2" method="GET">
```

This is wrong² because you miss a `;` and you put a constant instead of a string in the index:

```
<?php echo $_GET[Type] ?>
```

correct:

```
<?php echo $_GET['Type']; ?>
```

In js1 you miss `$.ajax({` + on line 4 `({` is not correct either.

Learn about [valid HTML, proper PHP](http://www.phtml.org) and some more basics I suggest, it can't work this way, especially not cross-platform compatible.

You can't copy scripts together from 100 tutorials and hope they will work, you have to know each command and line of code and what it does.